# Convert lo_get() result to text in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I was using `lo_import() + lo_get`functions to read file content in my server, but the result is not data we can read

code:

```
SELECT lo_import($$/home/x/web/a.php$$);
```

this will give an oid = 12312

then i can get file contet by using this oid:

```
SELECT lo_get(12312);
```

but the result was: " **i hide the rest of code, because afraid of sensitive data leaked** "

> \x3c3f7068700d0a66756e6374696f6e206563686f5f6d6f6e7468202824....

i read here [Importing bytea data into PostgreSQL by using COPY FROM stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117523/importing-bytea-data-into-postgresql-by-using-copy-from-stdin)
this maybe Base64 or Hex so i tried

```
https://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/HexDecode
https://www.base64decode.org/
```

but it gives me that the format is invalid .

also i checked the official document :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/lo-funcs.html

but its not clear what format is it

i also have checked this : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/using-postgresql-8-4-how-to-convert-bytea-to-text-value-in-postgres

but its far different from my question.

Comment: any solutions ?